# Recovering a crashed InputStream

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, classcastexception, recover

I'm writing a server and I'm using an `ObjectInputStream` to handle proprietary packets. I've recently been sometimes getting some unexpected `ClassCastException`s when I want call `objectInputStream.readObject()` and then trying casting them into the proprietary packets. I've been trying to trace the problem and I've been wondering whether it's because the `objectInputStream` is crashing due to some problem. According to the documentation for the method `objectInputStream.readObject()`... "All exceptions are fatal to the InputStream and leave it in an indeterminate state; it is up to the caller to ignore or recover the stream state."

I'm wondering what they mean by "recover the stream state"... is there a proper way for me to recover the objectInputStream or should I do a `socket.getInputStream()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your exceptions aren't caused by `objectInputStream.readObject()`, but by casting the (successfully returned) object to whatever it is you're trying to read, so the exception shouldn't affect the stream.

Comment: Well I'm suspecting that the ObjectInputStream is broken because after I get a ClassCastException my ObjectInputStream stops receiving packets from the client.

Comment: Is `readObject` throwing the exception or is the casting throwing an exception?

Comment: Well I see your point, that's what I suspected at first... why am I getting ClassCastExceptions when I know that I'm sending them correcting; by the way, the casts work 90% of the time, it's just sometimes it crashes. I tried a little experiment... trying to reload the ObjectInputStream after it crashes, so I'm calling `objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream);` and that throws a `StreamCorruptedException`.

Comment: Well that's not surprising because that means that it's getting an incorrect header, and since you're getting the stream in the middle, there's not going to be a correct header.

Comment: It might help to test the connection with something less fragile, like reading a sequence of bytes (if you haven't done that already).